# C# Web API with Windows Authentication - Get Local Windows Users Groups with readable group name- No AD

Tags: c#, windows, powershell

I would like to list all the groups that a local windows user is apart of. I can do this easily in PowerShell using these commands:

```
whoami /groups

gpresult /user <username> /r
```

I have gotten so far that I can get the groups but I can't get readable names, everything I get is a value like `S-1-1-0`. From looking at the command `whoami /groups` I can see that the `SID` is corresponding to this value and that they are correct. What do I have to add in order to get readable names?

```
var groups = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups;
```

To avoid the risk of duplicate question tag I have found a lot of answers using different AD methods like `new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)` from `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` but since this computer is not Active Directory connected I will get errors here. In this case `The server could not be contacted. - The LDAP server is unavailable.`. I can of course not do  `net user /domain <username>` either because of the same reason, the error here will be `System error 1355 has occurred.`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make a `PrincipalContext` with `ContentType.Machine`:

```
var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
var groupPrincipal = new GroupPrincipal(principalContext);
var principalSearcher = new PrincipalSearcher(groupPrincipal);
var searchResult = principalSearcher.FindAll();

foreach (var principal in searchResult)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(principal);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! However if I search for my user I only get three groups here, in `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups;` and the PowerShell commands I get 16 answers.

Comment: Hmm that's strange. For me it shows the exact same group names as the command "net localgroup". Maybe your c# application is running with different privileges as the poweshell?

Comment: I get that to but If I use `var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userName))` and then `user.GetGroups()` I only get three groups for my user. Your code will get all groups on the computer? For example it returns `IIS_IUSRS` that I know my current user is not apart of.

Comment: Because you are only part of these 3 local groups. See `net user [YourUserName]`

Comment: Alright, is there some way that I can get the names for the groups returned by `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Group‌​s;`? @Simon